# Solr query decision based on OR

Tags: java, solr

Is it possible to use one of the given queries in a `OR` statement if the first query does not return any result?

Given the following Solr query: `name:Mi OR name:Mi*`

If the left query does not return any documents, try the right side of the `OR` statement.

I have experimented with `qf` with no good results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are expecting from `OR` operator is a **conditional behavior**. The operators (`OR` and `AND`) defined in the Solr are for performing **union** and **intersection** of the results respectively. You can not achieve the **conditional** behavior out of it.

[Solr Boolean Operators](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Boolean%20operators)

Comment: Thank you. I thought Solr supported something like this. I hope they will add smarter search functions like this in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

Solr (Lucene actually) works in terms of MUST, SHOULD, and MUST NOT clauses. So, what you are asking does not exist directly.

However, you can do something similar by **ranking** your results appropriately. So, you would have your original value field and boost it high and then your copy of values in a - say - edgengram field to do suffix matches and boost it much less. Any results that matches perfectly will float to the top.

Comment: Thank you mister Alexandre, I will examine ranking more. I'm also experimenting with tokens and how the result(s) are being displayed. I really like Solr.